# Argument type X is not assignable to generic type T where X is specified as where clause

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following class

```
public class CalculatorManipulator<TCalculator>
        where TCalculator : CachableCalculator
```

it contains a dictionary  :

```
   protected Dictionary<string, TCalculator> Calculators { get; set; }
```

Let's say I try to add an item like so

```
Calculators.Add(calc.CustomCaption, new CachableCalculator(calc, fg, cache));
```

Why does this yield this compile time error :

```
Argument type CachableCalculator is not assignable to parameter type TCalculator.
```

The compiler knows that `TCalculator` is `CachableCalculator`.

I'm wondering why do I have to cast it when it can automatically do it.

This works by casting it to TCalculator

```
     Calculators.Add(calc.CustomCaption, (TCalculator)new CachableCalculator(calc, fg, cache));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Dog` is an `Animal`; that doesn't mean that you can assume that any `Animal` is a `Dog`, and throw everything into a kennel.

In this: `TCalculator` is the `Dog`, and `CachableCalculator` is the `Animal`. It is fine to treat `TCalculator` as `CachableCalculator`, but to do it in reverse: you need to tell the compiler that you know what you're doing, by adding an explicit cast.

Comment: But we are adding dogs >.<

Comment: @Chris you know that; the compiler doesn't; in fact, I don't think your code is valid - the dictionary is a `Dictionary<string,Dog>`, but you are **explicitly** adding an `Animal`, not  a `Dog` - `new CachableCalculator(...)` is **not** a `TCalculator`. It is a `CachableCalculator`. Your code will **only actually work** for `CalculatorManipulator<CachableCalculator>`

Comment: @MarcGravell is right with his comment, the code compiles with the cast but it will crash at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

To make this clearer, assume that you have this:

```
class Animal
{
}

class Dog : Animal
{
}

class AnimalManipulator<TAnimal> where TAnimal : Animal
{
    readonly Dictionary<string, TAnimal> animals = new Dictionary<string, TAnimal>();

    public void Test()
    {
        // Here you are forced to cast to the dictionary value type, because
        // what you are doing is NOT SAFE:
        animals.Add("Animal", (TAnimal)new Animal());
    }
}
```

Now we can show why the code above is not safe:

```
var test = new AnimalManipulator<Dog>();
test.Test(); // Runtime exception.
```

In this example, the type of `TAnimal` is `Dog`, which is ok as far as the generic constraint `TAnimal : Animal` is concerned.

However, when you call `Test()` the code will try to cast an `Animal` to a `Dog`, which is of course not allowed.

In terms of your types, you could have a class that derived from `CachableCalculator`, and use that with your `CalculatorManipulator`, which would result in the equivalent exception.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense to me now.